# wordpress theme duplicate showing in administration panel, but not in browser and preview

Tags: wordpress, themes

I made a few duplicates of my theme at http://www.elizabet.nl/wordpress.

All duplicates show correctly in the administration panel, different titles, different folders, different descriptions, etc.

However, only the old theme shows up, regardless of which theme dupliacte I activate in the administration panel.

Also in preview mode, every theme duplicate shows the original theme.

Themes are pretty much the same, just some minor differences. Headers are different.

Original theme (header):

```
/*
    Theme Name: New Theme 1
    Theme URI: http://www.elizabet.nl
    Description: Template
    Version: 1.0
    Author: H.M. Vos
    Author URL: http://www.hannemaatje.nl/
    Tags: black dark jugendstil

*/
```

Duplicates (headers):

```
/*
    Theme Name: Elizabet 1 AJAX
    Theme URI: http://www.elizabet.nl
    Description: Met AJAX implementatie, zonder content background graphics.
    Version: 1.0
    Author: H.M. Vos
    Author URL: http://www.hannemaatje.nl/
    Tags: black dark jugendstil
*/


/*
    Theme Name: Elizabet 2 AJAX
    Theme URI: http://www.elizabet.nl
    Description: Met AJAX implementatie en content background graphics.
    Version: 1.0
    Author: H.M. Vos
    Author URL: http://www.hannemaatje.nl/
    Tags: black dark jugendstil

*/
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Hannemaatje

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I used absolute links in my header and forgot to update these with the new folder name...
shame on me...